# ParseError: Bad Input on line 31

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Module Inputs
import turtle

# Define Functions
def drawshape(s,l,c):
    angle = 360 / s
    a.pencolor(c)
    for i in range(s):
        a.forward(l)
        a.left(angle)

# Create Turtle
a = turtle.Turtle
a.pensize(5)
a.pendown()

# Title and Credits
print('Shape Drawer by Alex Thornton')

# While Loop
answer = 'y'
while True:
    if answer != 'y':
        break

    # Create Turtle Window
    wn = turtle.Screen()

    # Inputs
    sides = int(input("\nHow many sides? ")
    length = int(input('What length of sides? ')
    color = input('What colour? ')

    # Call Functions from Inputs
    drawshape(sides,length,color)

    # Exit (From Turtle Window)
    wn.exitonclick()

    # Input For Restart
    answer = input("\nAgain? (y/n) ")

# Exit Program
print("\nThank you for using this program!")
exit = input('Please press enter to exit.')
```

on the length input, i get a parse error for bad input on line 31. this program takes input from the user on length of sides, number of sides and colour of shape. this is done as a GCSE computing homework.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mismatched parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a parenthesis on previous line 30 as well as on line 31.  A parse error often occurs on the previous line mentioned due to an incomplete line.

```
sides = int(input("\nHow many sides? "))
length = int(input('What length of sides? '))
```

Also line 13 needs parentheses to create an instance of `Turtle`.

```
a = turtle.Turtle()
```

Comment: ty! quite literally a schoolboy error. I'm a little rusty on python atm.